# Deleting all but latest revision of a file

Tags: windows, batch, deduplication

So I have these massive lists of drawings that I've done for work and I'd like to be able to dump them all into one folder and run a batch that would delete all of the older revs and leave the highest rev there. I'm not even sure this is possible without some seriously deep programming, so I thought I would ask here.

Example file names:

- 01-XY-001-Rev-0_1-6-2014.pdf
- 01-XY-001-Rev-2_1-13-2014.pdf
- 01-XY-001-Rev-9_2-1-2014.pdf
- 01-XY-001-Rev-11_2-4-2014.pdf
- 01-XY-002-Rev-0_1-7-2014.pdf
- 01-XY-002-Rev-4_1-13-2014.pdf
- 01-XY-002-Rev-7_1-26-2014.pdf
- 01-XY-002-Rev-11_2-4-2014.pdf
- 01-XXX-001-Rev-0_1-13-2014.pdf
- 01-XXX-001-Rev-4_1-21-2014.pdf
- 01-XXX-001-Rev-6_2-1-2014.pdf
- 01-XXX-001-Rev-10_2-4-2014.pdf

in the end, I want it to look like:

- 01-XY-001-Rev-11_2-4-2014.pdf
- 01-XY-002-Rev-11_2-4-2014.pdf
- 01-XXX-001-Rev-10_2-4-2014.pdf

so on and so forth.  Is this possible, keeping in mind that there are hundreds of these files with different names? The only think that is consistent is the Rev-1, Rev-2, Rev-3, etc. the rest changes as seen above, based on the drawing. I don't really see this as possible, but I'm willing to ask anyways.

Comment: Definitely possible. Does it need to be batch or can it be powershell/python/other?

Comment: Is it always the case that a higher rev implies a later date? How do you have forward slashes in your filenames?

Comment: I'm willing to try anything that you think would work, honestly.
Good catch, my bad there - they are dashes, not forward slashes. Habit. Lol

Comment: Yes actually, higher revs are always a later date - but not always the same date as others in the same rev. I see where you're going with this.  I was also just thinking, I have an index list that tells me what the current revs are suppose to be; although I'd have to pull the info manually off of a pdf.

Comment: @Helzehen If you have a list of the latest revisions, you could use that to copy those files in a separate folder. Then you could simply delete the rest.

Comment: @and31415 Yeah, I'd love to do that automatically - but it's the same as just pushing the delete key and manually going down through 5-800 files myself. Haha, I'm hoping there is just a simple 'program' that I can run to do it for me. :P because it's automated and awesome, of course (and maybe I'm a tad lazy).

Comment: I wouldn't say that I'm looking for software or a program, I meant more like a batch file, code, script, whatever you'd categorize this in. Bad habit of calling any complete lines of code, a "program."

Comment: @RJFalconer Did you have any suggestions or ideas of how this could be done in any form? The dates was a good catch, but how to make the code recognize the individual sets of filenames and then, from there, moving the latest one to another folder (or deleting the older ones if necessary)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're not a script writing service, but I had some time and interest so here ya go, in a PowerShell script:

```
#Set directory to search (. = current directory).
$dir = "."

#Get a list of all the files (only), sorted with newest on top.
$dirFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending

#Create an array to hold unique file name parts.
$uniqueFileNameParts = @()

#Create an array to hold final file list of files to keep.
$filesToKeep = @()

#Add the file name of the script itself to the files to keep, to prevent it from being deleted if it's in the same folder you're trying to clean.
$filesToKeep += $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name

#Loop through all the files in the directory list.
foreach ($file in $dirFiles) {
    #If it contains "-Rev-" pull the first part of the file name (up to and including "-Rev-").
    $filenameTokenLocation = $file.name.IndexOf("-Rev-")
    if ($filenameTokenLocation -ge 0) {
        $endOfString = $filenameTokenLocation + 5
        $subString = $file.name.Substring(0,$endOfString)

        #If the file name part doesn't already exist in the array, add it to it.
        if ($uniqueFileNameParts -notcontains $subString) {
            $uniqueFileNameParts += $subString
        } 
    }
}

#Loop through all the file name parts.
foreach ($fileName in $uniqueFileNameParts) {
    #Create a list of all files starting with that file name part, select the one file with the newest "LastWriteTime" attribute, and assign it to $latest.
    $latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | where {  $_.name.StartsWith($fileName) } | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
    #Add that file to the list of files to keep.
    $filesToKeep += $latest.name
}

#Get all files in the folder that are not in the list of files to keep, and remove them.
Get-ChildItem -exclude ($filesToKeep) | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | Remove-Item
```

Notes:

- It uses the Last Write Time of the file to determine which is the "latest", the time/date stamps in the file names themselves are not considered.
- It's case sensitive, so a file named `XYZ.txt` is not necessarily the same as one named `xYz.TxT`
- It isn't recursive, it only checks the folder/directory you aim it at, ignoring sub-folders.
- It dangerous as all get-out, so make a backup of the folder before trying it. :)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, I apologize if that's the case - I've been killing myself all week doing this (several thousand drawings) and didn't really think about that before submitting my post. Hopefully this works and I won't need to beat my head off of the wall anymore. Thanks again.

Comment: So, I ran it this morning and it didn't work - however it did give me about 200 "access denied" errors because it was trying to remove system32 files. I'm not really familiar with powershell, and I want to assume that this code wasn't intended as a joke/prank - so I must have done something wrong with it.  I wrote it into a .ps1 file and then executed it in Powershell. Oh well, I guess I'll just do this manually.

Comment: You'll want to run it in the folder you want to search/clean, OR change the `$dir` variable to the folder you want searched/cleaned.

Comment: I did that, as per the instructions in the code - but it didn't seem to matter.

Comment: Not sure what you tell you then. If it was trying to erase files in Windows/System32, then all things tell me you ran it in the wrong folder (Windows/System32 is where PS will start by default if you run it 'as administrator'). Copy the script to the folder you want to clean.  Open a PowerShell prompter and `CD` to that folder/directory.  Then run it by typing the name of the script file and hitting Enter.

Comment: I see what I did. Ran it again and it worked, but it deleted everything in the file instead of leaving behind the highest Revs.  Odd.

Comment: Little tweaking and it works great. Thanks again.

Comment: Excellent, good to hear. :)

Comment: For some reason, it's not looking at the LastWriteTime all of a sudden. It was working great, but now it's keeping 5-31-2012 Rev 7 and deleting 1-19-2014 Rev 11. It's already saved me a weeks worth of work though, so I'm still happy lol

Comment: Scratch that: I changed the way you have it Sorted to LastWriteTime instead of LastAccessTime and it's working again. Man this is useful! :D